# The program can't start because api-ms-win-downlevel-kernel32-l2-1-0.dll is missing - After UE4 update

Tags: windows-7, unreal-engine4

running Unreal Engine 4.26 on a Windows 7 machine. Recently updated from 4.25 to this version. Now getting this error..

[image]

> "The program can't start because
> api-ms-win-downlevel-kernel32-l2-1-0.dll is missing"

Anyone able to assist to advise please?

Comment: are you sure the DLL name is correct? I only find this topic while searching for the DLL and on my Win10 I also miss this DLL where VS2019 is installed

Comment: ok, the name is wrong. this dll is part of Windows Debugging tools from Windows 10 SDK

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, after a bit of digging and searching put it in this post and video:
https://www.georgenischal.com/blog/api-ms-win-downlevel-kernel32-l2-1-0-dll-error-unreal-4-26-2021.html

UE4 forum talking about the issue: https://forums.unrealengine.com/unreal-engine/feedback-for-epic/1850218-prgram-cant-start-cause-api-ms-win-downlevel-kernal32-blah-blah-dll-is-missing/page2

Msdownload page for DLL: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4507456

Seems its related to a windows security update. Please avoid downloading the DLL from dodgy search results on google or youtube which I almost did..

If you want to download a dLL, look on the links on my blogpost.. Google search is clearly broken, had to go down a few pages to find the result, all other links were spammy DLL download pages..